# `multind` prints empty index

Tags: indexing

I'm trying to run a document with multiple indices after reading [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing#Multiple_indices) and its reference, but my pdf's indices have no content. I've even run MakeIndex on the file, although I don't know if that applies when using `multind`. A short example I'm not able to run successfully is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multind}
\makeindex{books}
\makeindex{authors}

\begin{document}
Text\index{books}{b1}, text\index{authors}{a1}.

Text\index{books}{b2}\index{authors}{a2}. End of text.

\printindex{books}{The Books index}
\printindex{authors}{The Authors index}
\end{document}
```

The idx files are there and they have the info. What little trick am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-multind) you have to run

```
makeindex books.idx
makeindex authors.idx
```

The problem is that when you call `makeindex` from editor it runs on `main.idx`, where `main` is the name of your current `tex` file.

[image]

**Edit:** To configure TeXstudio (TeXmaker is similar, I guess) to run `makeindex` on all `idx` files on the current folder, pass `?*.idx` to the command, as shown in the image

[image]

Comment: My problem now is to use a wildcard or to pass multiple idx input to MakeIndex through command configuration in TexMaker... any idea?

Comment: I'm afraid TexMaker does not accept `*` nor `?*`

Comment: Install TeXstudio. It's very similar and much better than TeXmaker.

Comment: I don't think I'm in the right moment to change, but thanks anyway. By now I think I'll use a `.bat` to process every `.idx`

Comment: You don't need a `bat`. Just open the prompt windows and go to the folder containing the `idx` files and then  guess that you can type `makeindex *.idx`.

Comment: I know, but as I need to run it repeatedly I prefer to just doubleclick.